# how to override dependencies when using cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am upgrade diesel to 2.x right now, and I found the public rust lib uses the legacy diesel. Is it possible to force the diesel to use 2.x version? I have tried to add `cargo.override.toml` file in the root project directory and specify the version like this:

```
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "2.0.4", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono","serde_json"] }
```

then use this command to check the dependencies:

```
> cargo tree|grep diesel
├── diesel v2.0.4
│   ├── diesel_derives v2.0.2 (proc-macro)
│   ├── diesel v1.4.8
│   │   ├── diesel_derives v1.4.1 (proc-macro)
```

I am not sure the diesel using newest version? does the way I am force the version of project correct?

Comment: What would be the point of forcing a library that isn't written to work with diesel 2.0 to try to compile with it, that'd only result in compilation failure, remember major version changes come with breaking changes to the api, so the library that depends on the old `diesel` has to be changed to be able to work with the new `diesel` version.

Comment: got it, I will tried to upgrade the public lib, but it seems come out some issue.

Comment: Maybe the [Migration Guide](https://diesel.rs/guides/migration_guide.html) proves helpful in your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

What would be the point of forcing a library that isn't written to work with diesel 2.0 to try to compile with it, that'd only result in compilation failure, remember major version changes come with breaking changes to the API, so the library that depends on the old diesel has to be changed to be able to work with the new diesel version.

So no, it's not possible.